# Rails - How to avoid duplication between different applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture, code-duplication

This may seem quite a broad question, but I've searched around and didn't find ways to avoid duplication **between different apps**. Only inside an app.

I'm working with three different rails applications for some time now. From time to time I find myself refactoring some file like my `icons_helper.rb`. When I finish. Its better than before but different from the same file in my other two rails apps.

Other typical examples of duplicated code:

- Styles
- Layouts
- Messages (notices, alerts, ...)
- Etc.

What should I do to avoid this inter-app duplication? Is writing a gem that wraps those files the best choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simple, make your own gem. You can keep it closed (use `git: 'git location'`) or make it open and use rubygems.

You can start with `bundle gem yourgem`, and this is a very good article on [how to build your first gem](https://quickleft.com/blog/engineering-lunch-series-step-by-step-guide-to-building-your-first-ruby-gem/)

You manage this as a completely separate project. We are doing this in our company and it's working great

#### Update 1

As suggested, you want to have tests in your gem, for sure. It won't slow down debugging: errors raised by the gem are displayed as `gemname/file_in_gem:line_number` so you'll still detect problems easily. Also, if you are following good testing practices, you shouldn't test your gem in the other applications: the gem is already tested in its own codebase.

You might want to check this article about [splitting a rails application](http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-4-engines/) into a lot of sub-engines. Obviously this is an extreme approach which will provide good results only in very large projects and bigger teams, but it shows you that it's actually a good idea splitting a Rails application.

Comment: Doesn't it slow down debugging? I mean, by looking for the problem, switching to the gem project, searching inside, changing, testing the other 2 apps after each change?

Comment: First, you want to have tests in your gem, that for sure. But it doesn't slow down debugging: errors raised by the gem are displayed as `gemname/file_in_gem:line_number` so you'll still find problems easily. Also, if you are following testing practices, you shouldn't test your gem in the other two applications, that's already tested in the gem itself. About switching projects, my editor support fast switching with ctrl+alt+p, so I never feel "interrupted"

Comment: I understand. Can you update your answer with those comments about testing? btw, the link you provided is good.

Comment: Done, added also a good article about a company that brought it to the maximum, splitting the entire app into sub engines: http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-4-engines/ (very interesting article)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse code in multiple applications then I suggest to extract that code into a Gem and require that Gem in each application.